# Why doesn't it work with an average as it would with the sheer number "wind-speed"?

Tags: sql

I did the following:

```
select distinct year, month, day, wind_speed
    case
    when avg(wind_speed)>25 then 'HIGH'
    when avg(wind_speed) between 15 and 25 then 'MODERATE'
    else 'LOW'
    end as wind_severity
from station_data
order by avg(wind_speed) desc;
```

In the end it just shows one line of 28,000 possible entries. It must be approximately 10,000 if we only take one average per year!
Thanks!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: If you're using `DISTINCT` with aggregate functions, then that is normally a good indication that your `GROUP BY` clause is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an aggregation query with no `group by`.  Use `group by`:

```
select year, month, day,
       (case when avg(wind_speed) > 25 then 'HIGH'
             when avg(wind_speed) >= 15 then 'MODERATE'
             else 'LOW'
        end) as wind_severity
from station_data
group by year, month, day
order by avg(wind_speed) desc;
```

Note that `case` expressions are evaluated in order, so you don't need `between` for the middle one.